# Hibernate is deleting all tables when I run my App, using Spring Hibernate -> hbm2ddl is "validate"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am working for the first time on a Spring Hibernate Java Project and got some problems.

What I am doing:

want to save some data from different files into a database with different tables.
So I have created some repositorys and services..

Then I created two classes with methods to load the data. In booth classes I created an ApplicationContext.

Class A:

```
ApplicationContext context =
        new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(JpaConfig.class);
ExampleDataRepository exampleDataRepository =
        (ExampleDataRepository) context.getBean("exampleDataRepository");
AlsoExampleDataRepository alsoExampleDataRepository =
        (AlsoExampleDataRepository) context.getBean("alsoExampleDataRepository");
```

Class B:

```
ApplicationContext context =
        new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(JpaConfig.class);
NextExampleDataRepository nextExampleDataRepository =
        (NextExampleDataRepository) context.getBean("nextExampleDataRepository");
AlsoNextExampleDataRepository alsoNextExampleDataRepository =
        (AlsoNextExampleDataRepository) context.getBean("alsoNextExampleDataRepository");
ThirdExampleDataRepository thirdExampleDataRepository =
            (ThirdExampleDataRepository) context.getBean("thirdExampleDataRepository");
```

And in the Main Method App, I generated the Objects:

```
ClassA ca = new ClassA;
ClassB cb = new ClassB;
```

from here I call two methods to load the Data...
The Data get loaded right, but next time I start the application all tables get deleted, even if I don't call the methods to load the data. 
If I don't generate the objects to ClassA and ClassB the tables will not be deleted.

In my hibernate.properties the hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto is set to validate.

Is it right that I do something wrong with the ApplicationContext or the beans? if, what is the right way to do this and what solves my problem?

thanks for reading.

Comment: You are just getting the beans in ClassA and ClassB ... there is something wrong elsewhere ... you should add more information ...

Comment: You should always instanciate 1 context per app. Put your ApplicationContext in a singleton class

Comment: That being said, you can have more than 1 config file but using 2 instances of context is a bad design

Comment: Oh man, thanks alot, I found the misstake... In my JPAConfig Class I had it set to "create"... Your answer realy helped me, I was thinking I did it wrong with the ApplicationContext and did not check all the other things ;) thx.

Comment: Ok it is bad, what is the right way to do this with the ApplicationContext ??

Comment: create a Singleton and keep your instance of your context in it... when you need it, it will instanciate the first time...

Comment: I tried this http://sujitpal.blogspot.ch/2007/03/accessing-spring-beans-from-legacy-code.html but get an NullPointerException where I have to put this <bean id="springApplicationContext" class="com.mycompany.util.SpringApplicationContext"/> ??